# How can I add a macro in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, macros

I found that I can record a macro in Notepad++ and stop recording.

However once I've finished recording, it doesn't show any new macros for me to replay or add a shortcut key to access it.

An example would be:

1. Click *Macros* > *Start Recording*
2. Click *Plugins* > *NppExport* > *Copy all formats to clipboard*
3. Click *Macros* > *Stop Recording* to finish

How can I add this macro for replaying, and how can I assign a keyboard shortcut to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the rather simple method (simple once you find it anyway... it's not in the "Macro" menu):

1. From the top menu, select "Settings" => "Shortcut Mapper..."
2. Scroll down near the very bottom (my macros started at item 60)
3. Right-click and select either Modify or Delete (double click will act the same as selecting Modify)

Comment: How do I know which one is my macro when I haven't set a hotkey or name for it yet? edit: Ah, "Save Current Recorded Macro" next to the play/record buttons needs to be hit first... that's an important step.